# Npapi plugin crash in firefox

Tags: npapi, firebreath

I'm writing a npapi plugin can sign pdf document, my plugin worked in chrome, ie but in firefox when my plugin export a dialog as image i can't input anything then my plugin is crashed.
Can you tell me why i can't input anything when my plugin call a dialog of windows?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi there, did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the response to the same question you [asked on the firebreath-dev group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebreath-dev/O3pLN7lTAjQ):

`You must never block the main (UI) thread in a plugin.  Run your dialog on another thread and it'll probably work.`

Comment: That's very specific and useful, thanks! =] Note that I have run dialogs on other threads and had it work fine; if you're trying something similar, the problem may not be what you think.  On the other hand, it really isn't recommended to use dialogs with an NPAPI plugin.

Comment: Hi taxilian, thanks for your reply. I **have to** use dialog in NPAPI(client requirement) and my competitor has already implement it(this drives me crazy :-(...). Can you have a look of [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259432)?