# NPAPI plugin hang ui shows after modal dialog popup on firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, mfc, modal-dialog, npapi

Here is what I am trying to do: My partner's NPAPI plugin calls a function in my vc dll, My function displays a modal dialog and accepts user input. But after the dialog shows, firefox's plugin-hang-ui will popup after a few seconds and I have to manually close it or the NPAPI plugin will crashes after another few seconds.

```
HANDLE hThread - AfxBeginThread(DialogProc);//dialog diaplays in this thread
MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1,&hThread,FALSE,INFINITE,QS_ALLINPUT);
```

Besides, my dialog will cause UI to hang if I set firefox as my dialog's parent window(am using `getForgroundWindow()` to get the handle of firefox).

[image: just like this picture shows]

I have already tried google and I do found some similar questions([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190743)), but the answers of these questions didn't solve my problem.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of search and test, I finally found 2 ways to solve this problem.

1. Popup the modal dialog using win32 API `DialogBox` or `DialogBoxParam`, not MFC DoModal.

2.Using MFC DoModal but add a little trick in `OnInitDialog`, popup a messagebox and automatically close it right away. Then the dialog won't cuase the plugin to hang.

Both of 1)2) popup the dialog box in the main thread. I don't really understand why? It should be something related to windows message processing mechanism. Anyone who has any idea, we could discuss about it. :-)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but I'd say you either (a) don't understand what "blocking the main thread' means, or (b) this is triggering some strange behavior where there is a different thread of execution going on the main thread, which could be very very dangerous.  Either you are waiting (not returning from the function call from NPAPI) or you are not waiting (not blocking); if you are not waiting/blocking, you'll be fine.  If you are waiting/blocking then you're going to have problems.  It's not a complicated thing. If you need to wait for a dialog, wait in another thread.

Comment: If I wait for a dialog in another thread, then I have to wait for this thread in the main thread, that leads to the same situation. The point is I cannot return from the function until the dialog is closed by user. I don't know why but `DialogBox` makes the 'waiting/blocking' acting quiet normal in firefox plugin.

Comment: you aren't listening.  The NPAPI spec says you *must not do this*. Waiting on the main thread is completely forbidden. If you do this, you will get the dialog you are complaining about.  Period.  If you found a way that seems to avoid it then I *guarantee* that something dangerous is going on.  This isn't opinion, this isn't something that you can say "but my use case demands it".  Find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are blocking the main thread.  You may be opening the dialog on another thread, but when you do `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` that blocks until your other thread finishes.  Your function must return and cannot wait for the dialog.

Comment: I must wait until the thread finishes, or say all I want is the modal dialog box, I need the user input then continue running. I found some way to have this done, have a look of my answer if you want. :-)

Comment: ... seriously, you can't wait for the dialog.  By definition, if you are waiting for the dialog, *you are blocking the main thread*.  Blocking the main thread means "waiting for anything to happen for any period of time on the main thread".

Comment: You can have a simple test if there is VS/VC6 IDE on your pc.